# Phantom js : Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

This is my code of web scraping using headless browser phantom js

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
            File file = new File("src/main/resources/phantomjs.exe");
            String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            // capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
            // "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe");

            capabilities.setCapability(
                    PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
                    absolutePath);

            WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);

            driver.get("http://blah.blah.com/players/?ls=iref:nba:gnav");
```

Which is working fine and later I am bringing some links from there and doing next round of scraping

```
if (listOfPyalerLinks.size() > 0) {
            for (String url : listOfPyalerLinks) {
                try {
                    Player p = new Player();
                    driver.get(url);

                    WebElement position = driver.findElement(By
                            .xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'num-position')]"));
                    String positionvalstr = position.getText();
                    String positionval = positionvalstr.split("\\|")[1];
                    p.setPosition(positionval);

                    WebElement tabstats = driver.findElement(By
                            .xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'tab-career')]"));
```

The loop keep running and scraping data. But after sometime kind of 15 or 20 min I am receiving an error

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time: '2013-12-16 13:18:38'
System info: host: 'Sparity', ip: '172.28.220.143', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:276)
    at com.nbaparser.scrapper.service.impl.CrawlServiceImpl.parseDataFromLinks(CrawlServiceImpl.java:101)
    at com.nbaparser.scrapper.service.impl.CrawlServiceImpl.getNBAPlayerslinksList(CrawlServiceImpl.java:82)
    at com.nbaparser.test.CrawlTestCase.seleniumWithPanthamJSDriverTestCase(CrawlTestCase.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time: '2013-12-16 13:18:38'
System info: host: 'Sparity', ip: '172.28.220.143', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSCommandExecutor.execute(PhantomJSCommandExecutor.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:527)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.fallBackExecute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:319)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:298)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSCommandExecutor.execute(PhantomJSCommandExecutor.java:82)
    ... 28 more
```

What could be the possible reason ?

Comment: There are a lot of threads possibly on SO for `UnreachableBrowserException`, but a generous cause for this a connection time out between the server and the client you are using. I would suggest using updated versions of both to avoid such circumstances, though cannot assure if its a permanent fix.

Comment: Why not just add phantomjs executable to the environment path?

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida Is that really a problem ?? I am happily do that if that resolves my problem .

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Probably not going to fix your issue, no.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Probably not but you never know until you try, this seems to be a selenium-to-ghostdriver issue. You're using version 2.39 selenium, maybe try upgrading to 2.53. Had a similar issue but mine wouldn't even open phantomjs, updating selenium worked for me.